# Angular structural directive with CSS selector

Tags: html, angular, css-selectors, ng-template, angular-structural-directive

I am creating a custom dropdown menu.
The menu contains some items and should remain open when a user clicks on any of these items.
To check if the user clicks inside the dropdown menu I check via `window.onclick` if `event.target.matches('dropdown-content *')`. See the snippet below for context.

```
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-grid">
            <div class="add-offset">
                <div class="dd-header">
                    <div (click)="setupNewCol()"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-sign"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works, but when I add `*ngIf` to the div with the function call the CSS selector `'dropdown-content *'` doesn't seem to work anymore.
This is the HTML with the `*ngIf`

```
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-grid">
            <div class="add-offset">
                <div class="dd-header">
                    <div *ngIf="!settingNewOffset; else offsetSelection" (click)="setupNewCol()"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-sign"></i></div>
                    <ng-template #offsetSelection>
                        <div (click)="addCol()">
                            CLICK ME
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the introduction of the `*ngIf` in combination with `ng-template` the CSS selector doesn't recognize the clicks to be part of `'.dropdown-content *'` anymore. Why is this and what is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why it won't register the click on target 'dropdown-content' is probably because now the clicked target is a div, that does not have 'dropdown-content'. Probably the target parent has that class, but not the target.
2. To check if a user clicks on any of the items. You already have methods `addCol()` or `setupNewCol()`. If this method runs then user has clicked some of the item where the method was attached. You could also just attach another method to the item e.g `(click)="addCol(); onItemClick($event)"`

```js
onItemClick(event:any) {
console.log(event)
}
```

3. I don't see where the menu closing part is but using onItemClick you could just cancel that or try to cancel the event from propagating at all.

`(click)="addCol(); event.stopPropagation()"`